# Data Annotation validation not working in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

i am trying to implement data annotation. I have created a view model named **RegisterViewModel** with following data annotations.

```
namespace CSBSTest.ViewModel{public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Filed is required")]

    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Filed is required")]
    [StringLength(9,ErrorMessage ="The Registeration number is not valid")]
    [RegularExpression("BCS15[1-9][1-9][1-9]",ErrorMessage ="The CUST reg number is not valid")]
    public string RegNo { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Filed is required")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Filed is required")]
    [MaxLength(11)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MinLength(6,ErrorMessage ="Minimun length must be 6 charccters")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Compare("Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

}

then i have created a form for RegisterViewModel as below:

```
@model CSBSTest.ViewModel.RegisterViewModel@{
ViewBag.Title = "SignupForm";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NavBar.cshtml";}
<head>
<link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" /></head>
<h2 id="head">
Let's get Started
</h2>
<form action="~/Home/SignUp" method="post" style="padding:70px">
    <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Full Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4" placeholder="Muhammad Ali" @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputPassword4">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword4" placeholder="EaF@gmail.com" @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email)
    </div>

</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Password)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputAddress">Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>


</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputAddress2">Cust Reg No</label>
        <input type="datetime" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="20 May 1996" @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.RegNo)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.RegNo)
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="inputAddress2">Phone Number</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" placeholder="+92-3245009538" @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Phone)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        @Html.Label("Dept", "Select Department")
        @Html.DropDownList("Department", new SelectList(new[] { "IT", "CS" }), new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<button id="bt" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>


</form>
```

when i submit the form it gets submitted even if no field is being filled without showing annotation messages or it doesnt prevents from submitting empty form. I have tried adding validate and unobstructive libs in head but it still didnt worked.
Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry i intended to remove <input> tags i just forgot. i have used simple html.textboxfor and html.validataionmessagefor for each attribute but still it doesnt works, the form gets posted even with empty fields

Comment: Could you post the rendered html code of the entire page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the confusion here is because you are using both `<input>` tags and also the `Html.TextBoxFor` helpers. You don't need both, the `Html.TextBoxFor` method will actually produce the input tags for you. You can provide additional arguments to `TextBoxFor` in order to have your `<input>` tag include `class` attributes (and any other attribute you wish).

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/htmlhelper-textbox-textboxfor) for more information and good examples to follow.

I believe, if you correct your mixed tags, you'll find that the validation begins to work.

Comment: I did, but I (maybe incorrectly) assumed that the sample code provided is the result after the intended removal of `<input>` tags (i.e. incomplete).

Answer (score 0):

I was running the project with Ctrl+F5 and annotations werent working nor did CSS properly loaded. I restarted visual studio and runned the project in debug mode it worked correctly, 
thanks alot to all who have answered and helped.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check if your web .config have below code.

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

2) Please Check if you added reference of below Jquery files in your page or Layout page of your project.
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and jquery.validate.js